# Angular 17 ng build creates 'media' folder

Tags: angular

I can't seem to find ANY information relating to the source of the `/media` folder, at least it's not mentioned in the official docs under [build](https://angular.dev/cli/build#Arguments)

I'm using Angular CLI: 17.0.0

TL;DR

Angular creates a `/media/` directory outta thin air to store files referenced from the css of the components.

[image: see the 'media' folder?]

How do I indicate what the name of said folder should be? I don't want it to be called `/media`, it can be anything except that because I'm already using `/media` for Django via Nginx and I'd hate to go touch that part.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround for now at the Nginx level (although I'd still want to change the name from Angular build side of things)

Below, Nginx is serving files from two unrelated directories using the same URL endpoint of `/media/`. As in, when any requests matches `/media/` in the browser, Nginx will look into two folders before giving up with a 404

```
upstream frontend {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000; # angular ssr running via pm2
}

upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000; # django via gunicorn
}

server {
    server_name my.domain;
    root /path/to/angular/build/folder;


    # Configuration for the Frontend (Angular Server Side Rendering)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri @backend;
        # <--- This looks for requests (statics i.e js/css/fonts)
        # in /ssr/dist/browser folder. If nothing found, calls @backend
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
        # bla bla bla
    }

    # Configuration for the Backend (Django using Django Rest Framework)

    location /media/  {
        alias /home/verifine/apps/edu/media/;
        try_files $uri @angular-media;
        # The above `try_files` line is simply saying, when
        # that path is requested and no matching, try yet
        # another path, pointing to the named location block below
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/django/project/static/;
    }

    location ~ ^/(api|admin) {
        # bla bla bla
        proxy_pass http://backend; # this is for django
    }

    location @angular-media {
        root /home/verifine/apps/edu-frontend/browser/;
    }

    # ssl bla bla bla
}

server {
    # redirect bla bla bla
}
```

Looking forward to the original question answer though

Comment: could not make it work that way and ended up renaming the url routes on django side. would also be very interested in a way to change it on angular side.